# Is it possible to only time the subroutine call in Perl?

Tags: perl, profiling, subroutine

I am wondering if there is a Perl profiler out there that can profil the time spend in the subroutine call of a specific subroutine.

I do not want to time the whole subroutine (from call to return), but only the time spend by Perl in calling the subroutine (between call and the first instruction of the subroutine).

Is this possible ? (Whithout hand-adding time function in all my 90k line of code of course :))

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you need [`Devel::NYTProf`](http://p3rl.org/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf)'s line profiling mode. "Time on line" column will show you how much is spent on processing line where you make call, excluding time taken in called sub.